# Using a select in form for both new and edit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.1.1
```

In my helpers/roles_helper.rb, I have:

```
def roles_list_generator
  roles = Role.all.order(:role)
  if roles
    roles_matrix = [['','']]
    roles.each do |r|
      roles_matrix << [r.description,r.role]
    end
    return roles_matrix
  end
end
```

Then, I can use this in my views/users/form.html.erb:

```
    <%= f.select :role, options_for_select(roles_list_generator) %>
```

Which is rendered when I view new: views/users/new.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

The problem is that I can no longer form.html.erb with views/users/edit.html.erb.

I did try:

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(roles_list_generator), :selected => @user.role %>
```

But that did not work

## Solution:

This is what will go int form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(roles_list_generator, @user.role) %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it support to be [r.description,r.id] instead ?

Comment: Why would it be r.id if the value I want is r.role?

Comment: Somebody voted to close this question? I wish trolls would state why they voted the way they did.

Comment: Sorry, I guess its confusing Role.role. The best approach is to use id, name as the attributes so you can call Role.first.name. Thats why I put :id.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the advantage. My table has an ID field, a role and a description. For this particular form, I want to select the role and display the description. This however is not related to the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
f.collection_select :role, Role.all.order(:role), :id, :description
```

Then you can try to use your custom method - adding the prompt: true. This will remove the need to populate an empty entry.

```
f.collection_select :role, Role.all.order(:role), :id, :description, prompt: true
```

Here are the docs:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select